# SQL count function without limiting list due to WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I am pretty new to SQL and I am trying to generate a report that pulls from all kinds of different tables. The simple select lines that match up parts with KEYS is no problem.  Although I am running into issues when I am trying to count how many times ITEMID shows up in certain other tables.

One of the tables has a PARTID and all kinds of information about that part.  Then another table has PARTID and ITEMID (there is more than one item for each part).  Then the third tables has a row of ITEMID that shows up for each new Repaired item in the list.

I want to be able to say for a certain PARTID how many times does the associated ITEMIDs show up in the third table.  I have a code for this as follows:

```
SELECT 
    tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID,
    count(tblquarantaine.ITEMID) As 'Quarantine'

FROM tblensembleunepiece, tblitem, tblquarantaine

WHERE 
    tblensembleunepiece.NOPIECE<>'' 
    and tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID = tblitem.ENSPIECEID
    and tblquarantaine.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID

GROUP BY tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID;
```

This alone gives me a list of PARTIDs and how many times all their associated ITEMIDs show up into the third table.  Now if I do this again for another column with this code same principle:

```
SELECT 
    tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID,
    count(tblbonsortieitem.ITEMID)

FROM tblensembleunepiece, tblitem, tblbonsortieitem

WHERE 
    tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID = tblitem.ENSPIECEID
    and tblbonsortieitem.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID
    and tblbonsortieitem.VAREVENIR = 'true'

GROUP BY tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID;
```

This works too on its own and it counts the lines that appear in the third table for all ITEMIDs associated to a PARTID.

The problem comes when I try combining it all:

```
SELECT 
    tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID,
    tblensembleunepiece.NOPIECE As 'Part Number', 
    tblensembleunepiece.DESCRIPTIONENSP As 'Description', 
    tblensembleunepiece.QTEMIN As 'Min',
    tblensembleunepiece.QTEMAX As 'Max',
    tbltypepiece.TITRETYPE, 
    case 
        when CONSOMMABLE='true' Then 'Consumeable'
        else 'Rotable' end As 'Utilization',
    sum(tblitem.NBPOURPACK) As 'Serviceable',
    count(case when tblquarantaine.BER = 'false' Then tblquarantaine.ITEMID else null end) As 'Quarantine Repairable',
    count(case when tblquarantaine.BER = 'true' Then tblquarantaine.ITEMID else null end) As 'Quarantine BER/Scrap',
    count(case when tblbonsortieitem.VAREVENIR = 'true' Then tblbonsortieitem.ITEMID else null end) As 'Repair Line'

FROM tblensembleunepiece, tbltypepiece, tblitem, tblquarantaine, tblbonsortieitem

WHERE 
    tblensembleunepiece.NOPIECE<>'' 
    and tblensembleunepiece.TYPEPIECEID = tbltypepiece.TYPEPIECEID 
    and tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID = tblitem.ENSPIECEID
    and tblquarantaine.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID
    and tblbonsortieitem.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID


GROUP BY tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID;
```

What happens is that due to my WHERE statement it limits the amount of PARTIDs I will see now because I am imposing too many conditions and the list does not include all the parts I need to view.

How can I get all the PARTIDs I want and then fill in the values I need into the other 2 columns without imposing all the WHERE conditions?  if they dont show up in the third tables then the value would simply be zero.

Comment: If you are new to SQL you should be aware that implicit joins are a very poor practice and a SQL antipattern and were replaced with explicit joins in the last century. You should never write one of these again.

Comment: One more thing I cannot use many functions as the database was created a long time ago and has not been update since and I wont be able to get anybody to do anything about this because I am a student working.

Comment: How would an explicit join look like?

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: @HLGEM implicit joins are bad news in practice and still very much alive in DB theory courses at the graduate level. Don't shoot me, I'm just the messenger.

Comment: Pretty sure every decent modern db optimiser treats them the same as inner join syntax anyway I sincerely doubt that any db is naive enough to generate a huge Cartesian product of rows then scan it assessing the truth of the where predicate. It does make life hard work though, from a human understanding perspective

Comment: @nicomp, and when you encounter it in schooling, you should educate your professor on how incorrect it is to teach this.

Comment: @CaiusJard, the problems with Implicit joins have to do with the inaccuracy from missing a where clause when it gets complicated (thus producing an unintended cross join) and from the lack of understanding of how joins work meaning the dev doesn't really understand what he needs to do to get correct results. Additionally, left join syntax is often inaccurate and can produce incorrect results especially in SQL Server. Combining left joins explicit syntax and inner join implicit syntax has been know to create weird result sets as well. And you can't tell if a cross join is intentional or not.

Comment: I agree, though I'm not 100% sure it's related to what I meant, but perhaps what I said was misleading. You make a good point about deprecating use of WHERE to "perform" joining because missing a predicate can cause a cartesian. Not sure I've ever seen SQLServer perform a left join incorrectly, but I've seen plenty of occurrences of `SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b On a.id = b.id WHERE b.name = 'john'` and the dev can't understand why the left join "isn't working" - these are dev introduced bugs though rather than SQLS' fault. Have you got an example of a broken left join in SQLS?

Comment: @HLGEM LOL, no.  It's perfectly fine at the theoretical level.

Comment: @nicomp, no it isn't . Teaching people a coding technique they should never use in production is bad, Not teaching joins as joins and with an understanding of what an inner vice outer vice full vice cross join is is irresponsible. Database teaching at the collage level is atrocious which is part of why developers are so totally not ready for the workplace when they graduate.

Comment: @HLGEM Your incorrect assumption is that every topic in every DB course is directed at developers. You need to differentiate between theory and application. In Codd's relational algebra the natural join operator on two relations does not require a common field. The default is a Cartesian product. Yes, you wouldn't do it in the Real World, but it's still necessary to understand in a theory course. In fact, I teach it in my hands-on courses to illustrate how the cursor blows up when there is no explicit join field: please don't hate on me.

Comment: I am not assuming just application developers as I am not one.  I am a database specialist. And a Cartesian join is sometimes necessary in the business world, too. So yes of course they need to know about that, but there is an explicit join tor that too, so it is still no excuse to teach implicit joins. And thank you for teaching how a cursor can blow up. Better yet, teach them to avoid cursors as much as possible. Data students need to learn first to think in sets and to understand that data has meaning and how joins and where clauses, etc, are affected by that meaning.

Comment: Of course when I taught database students, I had to rearrange teh lessons as all of the textbooks started with the normal forms which is totally incomprehensible to someone who has never queried a database. It turns off the students and they stop paying attention. I had much more successful students when theory was the last thing I taught in a semester. Especially since I made them query non normalized as well as normalized databases in my exercises. Once they understood the pain of bad design, they were ready to understand how to do a good design.

Comment: @HLGEM Couldn't agree more about normalization.

Comment: Truly I was appalled that none of the textbooks we reviewed  were suitable for the order students need to learn things.

Answer (score 0):

So, a single Part has many Items and a single Repair job will have many Items involved in the repair.

```
Parts table
PartId, PartName
1, front-bumper
2, radiator-grille

Items table
PartId, Itemid, ItemName
1, 1, front-bumper-shell
1, 2, fog-light-assembly
1, 3, parking-sensor
1, 4, headlamp-washer-jet
2, 5, grille-mesh-plastic
2, 6, grille-mesh-metal
2, 7, jaguar-emblem-badge

Repairs table
RepairID, ItemID, WorkDone
1, 1, crash damage replace broken shell
1, 2, crash damage replace broken fog light
1, 6, crash damage replace radiator grille
1, 7, crash damage replace badge
2, 3, fix parking sensor 1
2, 3, fix parking sensor 2
```

And you want to know, for each repair job, how many distinct parts of the whole machine, had some item replaced?

```
SELECT
  RepairID, count(distinct PartId) as parts_affected
FROM
  Repairs r 
  INNER JOIN 
  Items i 
  ON
    r.ItemId = i.ItemId
```

The parts table doesn't need to be joined in if all we are doing is counting the distinct parts affected. The first job, crash damage to the front, affects two parts (bumper and grille). the second job, two broken parking sensors, affects just the bumper (1 part)

If I didn't follow your requirement correctly, let me know via comments - id appreciate if you could state your problem in terms of the tables I've posted (it's always easier to answer sql questions when example table structure and data is posted along with an expected report output )OR amend your question to have sample data and table structure and an expected output of the query